# Emulator cannot run because of Hyper-V Error

Tags: windows-phone, hyper-v, windows-phone-emulator

I have this error message:

> The windows phone emulator requires Hyper-V. Your PC is missing the
>   following pre-requisites required to run Hyper-V:

I cannot run my project on windows 8 phone emulator since days. I searched on internet, still I couldn't solve my problem. Everyone says open Control-panel, then click turn-off or turn on windows features, then choose hyper-v option. When I clicked turn off or turn on windows features there is no option about Hyper-V. Can anyone help me?

My computer features:
windows-8 Professional (64Bit)
intel core i7 processor
8Gb ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step
1- turn on hyper-v from bios

read this : 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/03/11/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-8-1.aspx

2- turn on hyper-v from windows

At the Start Screen, swipe the right hand side of the screen and select the Search Charm.

Type turn windows features on or off and select that item.

Select and enable Hyper-V.

If Hyper-V was not previously enabled, reboot the machine to apply the change.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted my os from windows 8 pro to windows 8 enterprise and I solved my problem easily.I know it is not a logic solution but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run Windows Phone 8 emulator you need to enable Hyper-V technology in the BIOS of your PC. See the [detailed article](http://itproguru.com/expert/2012/07/configure-bios-before-installing-windows-server-2012-and-hyper-v/) on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First you must turn on hyper-v from bios and then turn hyper-v from windows featured list restart and then will work ..

Comment: I'm having trouble following the steps, can you put them in a bullet list or format them in some other manner in order to separate them?